# Getting a val from an option tag inside a form. CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

The similar questions out there didnt really help me because they were too specific.

I have a form with a select input. I need the `val` that accompies the option tags.

When I `var_dump` the post data, I can see that the data being transferred is not the `val` of the option, but the name of the option.

i.e:

```
<select name="selector">
  <option val="1">Option 1</option>
  <option val="2">Option </option>
</select>
```

And my post data will say something like `["selector"]=>  string(8) "Option 1"`

I'm using CodeIgniter and I'm not sure how to get it to play along.

I want to avoid doing something convoluted with JavaScript and getting the `.val()` and assigning it to something else. That would be lame.

Comment: You have to use `value` instead of `val`. `<option value="1">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute you use to set an option value is `value` not `val`

```
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
```

Comment: Haha Its always the simple things. Too just Node.js for me lately

Answer (score 0):

While using codeigniter, better practice would be settings selects using form helper, so if we have array of options we can pass it into view and generate out like:

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('selector', $optionsArray, 0); ?>
```

this one will generate select dropdown like this:

```
<select name="selector">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">Option 1</option>
    <option value="1">Option 2</option>
    <option value="2">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Please notice that I set default selected value to 0

Cheers, hope this helps